# Can someone explain this nutrition label to me?

Tags: nutrient-composition

The math on the carbohydrates section doesn’t seem to add up... how to decipher this section of the label?

[image: Pepsi nutrition label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbohydrates and added sugars have different Daily Values (DVs). The DV for added sugars is 50 grams, 69g is 138% of 50g, so 138% of the recommended DV. The recommended DV for carbohydrates is 275g per day, and 69g is 25% of the carbohydrate DV.